# Synchronizing photos between PC, Android, IPhone

Tags: android, file-synchronization, dropbox

The question is more difficult than it seems.
In general, my goal is to make some ecosystem in order to view images on PC  from Android Phone or IPad/IPhone. Also view images on Android which stored on PC. Seems like it's a general synchronizing problem which can be solved by btsync. But I have some thoughts so may be there is another solution.

1. As I know (I can be wrong) btsync works with files. So I should choose folder DCIM to sync photos. Btsync knows nothing about content, only folder synchronization. So how will synchronization be between Android and iOS devices? May be would be better to use some soft like Dropbox or Yandex.Disk which know about photo content and offer to include "Photos" for synchronization?
2. When I imagine what I want I imagine NAS. It would be global storage where photos would be uploaded to and I could view images from devices via wifi/internet. (I also can be wrong here). What can you say about RaspberryPI+HDD as a NAS?

Sorry for uncertain question. May be you share your usecases. At the moment I inclined to think btsync is the best solution.

Comment: Have you tried Dropbox, and what didn't you like about it? Do you prefer a local or a cloud storage?

Comment: Google Photos is free with lower resolution which would seem to me to work.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Google Drive](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive) to share pics between my PC, iPad, and Android phone. Odds are it would work just fine with an iPhone and Android tablet too. It comes with 15 GB of free storage, and it's extremely simple to use.

**Adding Photos**

On Windows, it acts just like a normal directory, complete with subdirectories and all. Anything added to it is automatically synced.

On iOS, you can open the app and go to whichever subdirectory you want, then tap the "+" icon in the upper right, select *Upload Photos or Videos*, select *Camera Roll* (or wherever else you might have them), tap whichever ones you want to upload, and then tap the checkmark icon in the upper right.

On Android, you can upload photos from within the app too, but I can only figure out how to upload one at a time there. Luckily, though, you can upload multiple pics directly from your Gallery. Go into any album, then press-and-hold on a pic, and checkboxes will appear over each pic, with the first one you pressed already checked. Tap other pics if wanted, then click the share icon, pick Drive as the destination, make sure the desired folder is selected at the bottom, and then click OK.

Those explanations make it sound harder than it really is. It's actually pretty intuitive, as long as you remember to upload from the Gallery instead of the app itself on Android.

**Viewing Photos**

Viewing the pics from any of the three platforms is a piece of cake too. On the PC, you just open them like any other photo files, in your favorite photo viewer. On the mobile devices, you can open them in Drive and it has a good photo viewer built in, complete with left/right swipe support. Nice and smooth.

Comment: Yeah.. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned RaspberryPI, you might find that [Perkeep](https://perkeep.org/) by [Brad Fitzpatric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brad_Fitzpatrick) (the original creator of LiveJournal's photo hosting system) is targeting a similar use case. There has been an Android client since early on in the project, but I'm not sure the iOS client is anywhere near being usable.